# Formatting date/time in custom timezone in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a requirement to create a custom timezone (New York + 7 hours with US DST setting) and parse/format date using this.

In Java I would typically do this:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"); // Get new york tz
tz.setRawOffset(tz.getRawOffset() + 7 * 3600 * 1000); // add 7 hrs

DateFormat nyp7 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
nyp7.setTimeZone(tz);

DateFormat utc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
utc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

// US DST not in effect, NY is UTC-5, NY+7 is UTC+2
// below result is "2013-03-01 14:34:55"
nyp7.format(utc.parse("2013-03-01 12:34:55")); 

// US DST in effect, NY is UTC-4, NY+7 is UTC+3
// below result is "2013-04-01 15:34:55"
nyp7.format(utc.parse("2013-04-01 12:34:55"));
```

How to do equivalent in C++? I've been digging boost date time library but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by creating a custom timezone:

```
using namespace boost;
using namespace local_time;
using namespace gregorian;
using posix_time::time_duration;
using posix_time::ptime;

// Create a new timezone names
time_zone_names tzn("New York Plus 7 Time", "NYP7",
                    "New York Plus 7 Daylight Time", "NYP7D");

// With base UTC offset +2
int base_utc_offset_hr = 2;
time_duration utc_offset(base_utc_offset_hr,0,0);

// DST offset is +1 and starts and ends at 9am (2am + 7)
local_time::dst_adjustment_offsets adj_offsets(time_duration(1,0,0),
                                               time_duration(9,0,0),
                                               time_duration(9,0,0));

// DST starts the second Sunday of March and ends last Sunday of Nov
nth_kday_of_month start_rule(nth_kday_of_month::second, Sunday, Mar);
last_day_of_the_week_in_month end_rule(Sunday, Nov);
shared_ptr<dst_calc_rule> nyp7_rules(new nth_last_dst_rule(start_rule, end_rule));

// Construct the custom timezone
time_zone_ptr nyp7(new custom_time_zone(tzn, utc_offset, adj_offsets, nyp7_rules));
```

This can then be used to detect whether or not DST is in effect, and offset it into the source time

```
// Determine whether or not dst in effect for time 't'
ptime dst_start = nyp7->dst_local_start_time(year);
ptime dst_end = nyp7->dst_local_end_time(year);
bool dst_on = dst_start <= t && t < dst_end;
```

And subsequently the parsing and formatting can be done according to boost's user manual:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html